# Invalid argument when creating S3 to BigQuery Transfer using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create a BigQuery Transfer from S3 bucket to BigQuery dataset using Terraform. Despite consulting the docs and looking through terraform debug logs I cannot fix the `Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument.` error.

I attach the configuration used to create S3 transfer as well as configuration of `scheduled_query` transfer that is created without any problems.

```
data "google_project" "project" {
}

resource "google_service_account" "bigquery_transfer_account" {
  account_id   = "bigquery-transfer-account"
  display_name = "bigquery-transfer-account"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "permissions" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  role    = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
  member  = google_service_account.bigquery_transfer_account.member # "serviceAccount:service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "transfer-permissions" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  role   = "roles/iam.serviceAccountShortTermTokenMinter"
  member = "serviceAccount:service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "query_config_test" {
  depends_on = [google_project_iam_member.permissions, google_project_iam_member.transfer-permissions]

  display_name           = "my-query"
  data_source_id         = "scheduled_query"
  disabled = true
  location               = "EU"
  destination_dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.transfer.dataset_id
  params = {
    destination_table_name_template = "my_table"
    write_disposition               = "WRITE_APPEND"
    query                           = "SELECT 1 AS a"
  }
  service_account_name   = google_service_account.bigquery_transfer_account.email
  # service_account_name    = "service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "amazon-transfer" {
   depends_on = [google_project_iam_member.permissions, google_project_iam_member.transfer-permissions]

  display_name           = "transfer-s3-to-bq"
  location               = "EU"
  disabled = true
  data_source_id         = "amazon_s3"
  destination_dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.transfer.dataset_id
  params = {
    access_key_id                   = aws_iam_access_key.bigquery_transfer.id
    destination_table_name_template = "my_table"
    data_path                       = "s3://bq-source/*.csv"
    file_format                     = "CSV"
    skip_leading_rows               = 1
    write_disposition               = "WRITE_APPEND"
  }
  sensitive_params {
    secret_access_key               = aws_iam_access_key.bigquery_transfer.secret
  }
  service_account_name   = google_service_account.bigquery_transfer_account.email
  # service_account_name    = "service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

`terraform apply` produces the following output:

```
...
  # module.bigquery_dump.google_bigquery_data_transfer_config.amazon-transfer will be created
  + resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "amazon-transfer" {
      + data_source_id         = "amazon_s3"
      + destination_dataset_id = "transfer"
      + disabled               = true
      + display_name           = "transfer-s3-to-bq"
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + location               = "EU"
      + name                   = (known after apply)
      + params                 = {
          + "access_key_id"                   = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
          + "data_path"                       = "s3://bq-source/*.csv"
          + "destination_table_name_template" = "raw_events"
          + "file_format"                     = "CSV"
          + "skip_leading_rows"               = "1"
          + "write_disposition"               = "WRITE_APPEND"
        }
      + project                = (known after apply)
      + service_account_name   = "bigquery-transfer-account@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

      + sensitive_params {
          + secret_access_key = (sensitive value)
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
module.bigquery_dump.google_bigquery_data_transfer_config.amazon-transfer: Creating...
module.bigquery_dump.aws_security_group.bigquery_dump: Modifying... [id=sg-0c0d14bc1db66f430]
module.bigquery_dump.aws_security_group.bigquery_dump: Modifications complete after 1s [id=sg-0c0d14bc1db66f430]
╷
│ Error: Error creating Config: googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument.
│ 
│   with module.bigquery_dump.google_bigquery_data_transfer_config.amazon-transfer,
│   on ../../modules/aurora_to_bigquery_transfer/bigquery.tf line 77, in resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "amazon-transfer":
│   77: resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "amazon-transfer" {
│ 
╵
```

I've tried to use BQ's service account (as you can see it is commented out, but changing it doesn't fix the problem), successful creation of scheduled transfer seems to confirm that I have correct permissions and my account is set up correctly.

I've consulted the [S3 transfer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/s3-transfer/) to see if I've provided every required argument. I've enabled terraform debug log to see the actual API Calls, there is no additional info in the log (redacted log attached)

```
-----------------------------------------------------: timestamp=2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100
2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.51.0_x5: 2023/02/06 13:02:40 [DEBUG] Creating new Config: map[string]interface {}{"dataSourceId":"amazon_s3", "destinationDatasetId":"transfer", "displayName":"update_order", "params":map[string]string{"access_key_id":"xxxx", "data_path":"s3://xxxx/*", "destination_table_name_template":"xxx", "file_format":"CSV", "secret_access_key":"xxx", "write_disposition":"WRITE_TRUNCATE"}}: timestamp=2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100
2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.51.0_x5: 2023/02/06 13:02:40 [DEBUG] Waiting for state to become: [success]: timestamp=2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100
2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.51.0_x5: 2023/02/06 13:02:40 [DEBUG] Retry Transport: starting RoundTrip retry loop: timestamp=2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100
2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.51.0_x5: 2023/02/06 13:02:40 [DEBUG] Retry Transport: request attempt 0: timestamp=2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100
2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.51.0_x5: 2023/02/06 13:02:40 [DEBUG] Creating new Config: map[string]interface {}{"dataSourceId":"amazon_s3", "destinationDatasetId":"transfer", "displayName":"update_user_action", "params":map[string]string{"access_key_id":"xxxx", "data_path":"s3://xxx/*", "destination_table_name_template":"xxx", "file_format":"CSV", "secret_access_key":"xxx", "write_disposition":"WRITE_TRUNCATE"}}: timestamp=2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100
2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.51.0_x5: 2023/02/06 13:02:40 [DEBUG] Waiting for state to become: [success]: timestamp=2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100
2023-02-06T13:02:40.149+0100 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.51.0_x5: 2023/02/06 13:02:40 [DEBUG] Google API Request Details:
---[ REQUEST ]---------------------------------------
POST /v1/projects/xxxxx/locations/EU/transferConfigs?alt=json&serviceAccountName=xxx@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com HTTP/1.1
Host: bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com
User-Agent: Terraform/1.3.6 (+https://www.terraform.io) Terraform-Plugin-SDK/2.10.1 terraform-provider-google/4.51.0
Content-Length: 423
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{
 "dataSourceId": "amazon_s3",
 "destinationDatasetId": "transfer",
 "displayName": "update_order",
 "params": {
  "access_key_id": "xxxx",
  "data_path": "s3://xxx/*",
  "destination_table_name_template": "xxx",
  "file_format": "CSV",
  "secret_access_key": "xxx",
  "write_disposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
 }
}

2023-02-06T13:02:41.461+0100 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-google_v4.51.0_x5: 2023/02/06 13:02:41 [DEBUG] Google API Response Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/2.0 400 Bad Request
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2023 12:02:41 GMT
Server: ESF
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 0

{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```